# When is the splitting field of $x^n-a$ abelian?

Tags: number-theory, field-theory, galois-theory, kummer-theory

Let $K$ be a number field and $a \in K^\times$ an element that is not an $n$-th power.  Is it true that the splitting field of $x^n-a$ is abelian if and only if $\zeta_n \in K$?

I know one direction is true: if $\zeta_n \in K$, then $K(\sqrt[n]{a})$ is the splitting field, hence every automorphism is determined by the image $\sqrt[n]{a} \mapsto \zeta_n^k \sqrt[n]{a} $. Therefore $G$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.

The opposite direction is harder.
In this case, I would love to say that the extension $K(\sqrt[n]{a})$ is not normal (thus, corresponding to a non-abelian subgroup of $G$). If it were normal, it would contain all roots of the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt[n]{a}$, in particular some $\zeta_n^r\sqrt[n]{a}$ and their quotient $\zeta_n^r$. If $n=p$ is prime, this provides a contradiction, since the dregee of $K(\zeta_p)/K$ is prime to $p$, which is the degree of $K(\sqrt[n]{a})/K$. In the general case two problems arise:

- if $r$ is not prime to $n$, then $\zeta_n^r$ is allowed to be in $K$ and $K(\sqrt[n]{a})$ might be a splitting field!
- if $r$ is prime to $n$ (or, say, we decide we contempt ourselves with the case of $n$ prime) we conclude that $K(\sqrt[n]{a})$ is the splitting field of $x^n-a$, but I am not sure how to exclude the possibility

Any idea?

Comment: As you say: a normal extension contains *every* root. So it also contains $\zeta_n \sqrt[n]{a}$. You don't need to worry about if $r$ is prime to $n$ or not.

Comment: @TrevorGunn Yess! But $x^n-a$ might not be the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt[n]{a}$.

Comment: You definitely need some extra assumptions. Otherwise $x^4 + 1$ is an easy counterexample.

Comment: Another interesting example:  $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[6]{-3})$ contains $\sqrt{-3}$ and thus also $\zeta_6 = -\zeta_3 = -\frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{-3}}{2}$, making it normal.  But it's not abelian:  it contains the subfield $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]{-3})$, which has one real and two complex embeddings and is therefore non-normal.

Comment: Some references you might find helpful:  Rajat Tandon, "Roots are Not Contained in Cyclotomic Fields", and Jacobson-Vélez, "The Galois group of a radical extension of the rationals".  The former shows that the $\mathrm{Gal}_{\mathbb Q}(x^n - a)$ is never abelian when $n > 2$, $a > 1$, and $\sqrt[n]a$ can't be rewritten as a lower-order root.  The latter gives a complete description of $\mathrm{Gal}_{\mathbb Q}(x^n - a)$ when this polynomial is irreducible.